# Practical applications of Graeffe's root finding method

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots, mathematica

What are the practical applications of Graeffe's root finding method? I searched a lot but couldn't find any. I found that it is used in aerodynamics and electric circuit analysis. But I don't know much about that.

Comment: Probably the same uses as any other root-finding algorithm for polynomials.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeffe%27s_method

Answer (score 1):

The Graeffe iteration itself is used in other root finding schemes as a means to compute correct inner and outer root radii. See for a quite graphical example Dedieu/Yakoubshohn on the [Bisection-Exclusion algorithm](http://perso.math.univ-toulouse.fr/yak/files/2018/09/JoC-2005.pdf) in the complex plane.

Schönhage's [*circle splitting method*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.123.3313&rep=rep1&type=pdf) uses it to find areas with many roots and to find their factor in the polynomial. (But then you may ask, where is the circle splitting method actually implemented for wide use...)

It would also be interesting to know if the *["Tangent Graeffe iteration"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9908150)* by Malajovich/Zubelli (2001) using a special data type of dual numbers, with a renormalization to drastically extend the range of the floating point exponent, has seen any practical application.

Answer (score -1):

I used this method to find practical approximation in the problem of the comparison of 2 binomial samples.